# How to make only portion of text to handle the click

Tags: android, textview

I have a textview where i will display both text and some links like 'check out www.google.com'.I am using spannable to set the www.google.com as clickable and i am handling the click event successfully.The problem is when i click on the www.google.com the entire textview is taking the click.I want the rest of the data to be non clickable and only www.google.com to be clickable.

Further information i am making the textview as spannable,is that a problem?

Answer (score 1):

use `android:autoLink="web"` in your textview tag.

Comment: you need not handle any click listener for this..if you have removed the click listener then show ur textview code...

Comment: i need to handle the click event because i have to perform few operations on clicking the link.And i am able to do it properly.Point is on clicking the link the entire content inside textview gets clicked whereas i want only the link to be clicked.The entire textview becomes clickable.